# Proof of FOIL Modern Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, formal-proofs

I am trying to work through Birkhoff's A Survey of Modern Algebra independently, but am having difficulty getting off the ground with the proofs based on laws, rules, etc.  I come from mostly soft analysis, and this is foreign.  One problem is to prove (a+b)(c+d)=(ac+bc)+(ad+bd), using the properties of a commutative ring.  Could someone please walk me through the proof, and how to do these in general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$(a+b)(c+d)=a(c+d)+b(c+d)$ by distributive law.

$a(c+d)+b(c+d)=(c+d)a+(c+d)b$ by commutativity of multiplication.

$(c+d)a+(c+d)b=(ca+da)+(cb+db)$ by distributive law twice.

$(ca+da)+(cb+db)=(ac+bc)+(ad+bd)$ by associativity and commutativity of addition.

Comment: Perhaps the second step was overkill. This was in case the distributive law only existed on the left in that book.

Comment: Thank you!  The distributive law is only left originally, so I needed that step.

Comment: No, the second step was apt because you would anyhow need to apply to apply the commutativity of multiplication to get the form required. You've applied it at a phase where there existed minimum free elements (consider those in brackets as one element)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Start from the RHS and try to manipulate it into the LHS. For each bracketed pair, factor something out. This factoring is an application of distributivity. After doing this, apply distributivity a third time, and we're done.